# Python pandas date time, how to convert these dates to pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

My dates are of the form Month, Year:

`82013`

`102013`

But I want them to be regular pandas datetime. When I insert these dates into pd.datetime I get

`1970-01-01 00:00:00.000082013`

This is very wrong.

Advice would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you in control of how the dates are created? The problem should be solved up-stream of this code, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's standard `datetime` module:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 16 2019, 19:49:22) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('82013', '%m%Y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('102013', '%m%Y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 1, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Dates generated that way are going to be set to the first day of the month at zero hour and zero minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As roganjosh said, it would be better if you could just get your dates in an easier format in the first place. However, if you're stuck with this, can get by with just telling pd.to_datetime the [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you expect.

```py
dates = pd.Series(['82013', '102013'])
pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%m%Y')
```

Comment: This is a good answer (+1). However you might want to convert to string beforehand in case they are integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
df

     date
0   82013
1  102013
```

First, extract the month and year as separate columns using `str.extract`:

```
u = df.date.astype(str).str.extract(r'^(?P<month>\d{1,2})(?P<year>\d{4})$', expand=True)

  month  year
0     8  2013
1    10  2013
```

Now, let `pd.to_datetime` take over.

```
pd.to_datetime(u.assign(day=1))

0   2013-08-01
1   2013-10-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If invalid values are possible, use

```
pd.to_datetime(u.assign(day=1), errors='coerce')
```